# readLine() doesn't wait for user input in Kotlin/Native

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

Here is a simple script

```
fun main() {
    print("ready> ")
    val input = readLine()
    println("User input: $input")
}
```

When I run this program with `gradle runReleaseExecutableMacos` I expect that I'll see a `ready>` prompt and will have a possibility to type some chars. But this program finishes immediately with `User input: null` as a result.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `readLine()` ==> `readLine()!!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve the behavior you desire, you can run the executable file produced by the Gradle. It will have an extension `*.kexe`.

---

Also, you can extend your `build.gradle` file with additional parameter. you got to add something like this:

```
macosX64("macos") {
    binaries {
        executable {
            runTask.standardInput = System.in
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use ticks around 'in'

```
    macosX64("macos") {
        binaries {
            executable {
                runTask?.standardInput = System.`in`
            }
        }
    }
```